# Unable to access if port number is changed

Tags: jenkins, rhel7

The request is to change port number of jenkins site as the default port 8080 is not allowed inside our organization.

Hence I have changed the port to 6052 or 9999 but the site is not accessible , if I change back the default port 8080 or 8088 the site is working ..

Can anyone advise what could be the reason??
Is anything else I should do

I have altered the settings in /etc/sysconfig/jenkins
/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `Jenkins URL` setting under `Manage Jenkins - System Configuration - System` first. Jenkins often runs behind a reverse proxy and can't make assumptions about its url.

Answer (score 0):

First open the ***/etc/default/jenkins*** file.
Then under JENKINS_ARGS section, you can change the port like this

`HTTP_PORT=9090.`

Then you should restart Jenkins with `sudo service jenkins restart`.

Then to check the status use this command sudo systemctl status jenkins

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9z7j.png)

**OPTION 2:**
open this file
***/usr/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service***

and put this line

```
Environment="JENKINS_PORT=8080"
```